# Iterate through Data Validation List

Tags: vba, excel

i created a button which is this macro on it:

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()
     Dim inputRange As Range
     Dim c As Range
     Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("A9").Validation.Formula1)
     path = "C:\test\"
     For Each c In inputRange
        filename1 = Range("B18").Text
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=path & filename1 & ".xlsm"
    Next c
End Sub
```

the list of the validation contains about 5 names. but for some reason it only saves 1 file.

Comment: You never use `c` in the saveas.  it is always `filename1 = Range("B18").Text`  You need to iterate the name or it is just saving it as the same file five times.

Comment: when the input of the cell of A9 changes. the cell of B18 changes as well. so it should make different filenames. but for some reason it isnt iterating at all.

Comment: Step through you code and make sure it is changing as it loops

Comment: Range("B18") will not change unless you do something inside the loop that will make it do so based on `c`.  something like `Range("A9").value = c` then make sure you calculate the worksheet before taking the value from B18.

Comment: @ScottCraner what is the command to calculate the worksheet? because right now whenever i look in the worksheet and press the button none of the values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As far as you are not having problems with accessing the data validation list, I have hardcoded it in `Range("A1:A5")`.
- I have changed `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` to see how it works as well. 
  -`ThisWorkbook.Save` is needed to produce valid `.FullName` and valid `.Path`
- The tricky part is to save the `oldPathFull` and the `oldPath` of the excel file and to use `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs oldPathFull` on every loop.
- `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` disables the Excel prompts. You can put it outside the loop, if you feel like it.

---

```
Sub LoopThroughValidationList()

     Dim inputRange     As Range
     Dim c              As Range
     Dim oldPathFull    As String
     Dim oldPath        As String

     Set inputRange = Range("A1:A5")
     ThisWorkbook.Save
     oldPathFull = ThisWorkbook.FullName
     oldPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

     For Each c In inputRange
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=oldPath & c & ".xlsb"
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs oldPathFull
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next c

End Sub
```

---

Once you are able to get the code running with predefined values, this is a [MCVE] example how to get the data validation values of a cell `B1`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell              As Range
    Dim valRules            As Range

    Set valRules = Evaluate(Range("A1").Validation.Formula1)

    For Each myCell In valRules
        Range("A1") = myCell
        Debug.Print Range("A1")
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

I putt your code in but for some reason it also only saves 1 file. it wont iterate trough the data validation list or something.

Comment: @Klaas - what happens if you  write some values in `A1:A5`? Does it save it 5 times?

Comment: Yes. but i need that list because the whole file changes depening of the value of that list.

Comment: right now i changed my code but it saves the file 5 times with only 1 name the one that is currently selected in the list and it wont iterate trough to the next one.

Comment: @Klaas - See the edit. Then try to build up the two codes into one.

Comment: Hi,

Right now it prints all the names that are in the list.
Whenever i change the file however to this. https://pastebin.com/ it only saves one file. and not all the files. 
the thing is that when the value in the list changes a lot of numbers in the excel file change. but when i run the macro i dont see that the value of the list cell changes.

if i only do save mycell it makes 5 files with the right names. but i need another cell that changes value depening on the name of the list value

Comment: @Klaas - see the edit of the 2. code - it changes the selected cell with the one from the validation.